# Matplotlib matshow while centering the yticklabels top and bottom row gets trimmed

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code i want to display a square matrix with yticklabels in the center of each cell but top and bottom row are trimmed. How to avoid this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=10
mat = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(n, n))

classes = ['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E' ,'F' ,'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']

df = pd.DataFrame(mat, columns=classes, index=classes)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

im = ax.matshow(df, interpolation='none')
fig.colorbar(im)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n))
ax.set_xticklabels(classes)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(n))
ax.set_yticklabels(classes)

for (i,j), z in np.ndenumerate(df):
    ax.text(j, i, str(z), ha="center", va="center")

ax.set_title("Matrix")

plt.show()
```

[This is what i get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x771j.png)

Comment: In my environment, it is displayed correctly without cutting up and down.

Comment: @r-beginners thank you,  yes there was something wrong with my environment. i got the correct plot after reinstalling.